# Handling escape characters on custom language

Tags: c#, language-design

I'm working on a new feature for a C# application that will process a text given by the user. This text can contain any character, but everything that is between braces ({}) or between brackets ([]) will be treated on a special way (basically, the text inside brackets will be replaced for another text, and the braces will indicate a subsection in the given text and will be processed differently).

So, I want to give the user the choice to use braces and brackets on his text, so the first thing I thought was to use "{{" to represent "{", and the same for all other special characters, but this will give problems. If he wants to open a subsection and wants the first character in the subsection to be "{", then he would write "{{{", but that's the same thing he would write if he would like the character before the subsection to be "{". So this causes an ambiguity.

Now I'm thinking I could use "\" to escape braces and brackets, and use "\\" to represent "\". And I'm kinda figuring out how to process this, but I got a feeling I'm trying to reinvent the wheel here. Wonder if there is a known algorithm or library that does what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use XML tags instead of special characters?

```
<section>
Blah blah blah blah <replace id="some identifier" />
</section>
```

This approach would let you parse your text using any XML parser in Microsoft .NET and any other platform. And you'll save time because there's nothing to escape.

Comment: The problem is that the kind of text they'll enter is most likely HTML and XML, so they would need to escape every '<' and '>'.

Comment: Unless they use CDATA. The other good thing about this approach is that later on if I want to add functionality I don't need to redefine the language. I'll think about it :)

Comment: But if it's HTML and XML, what's the problem about introducing custom elements for processing?

Comment: Is not necessarily going to be XML and I don't want to tie them to have to use valid XML or HTML. It can be anything, but will most likely be XML and HTML.

Comment: It sounds like you're almost trying to invent a custom template processing language.. have you looked at the way more mature solutions handle this scenario? NVelocity, Spark View Engine, Razor, T4 etc etc

Comment: @MattDavey: Seems to me like they compile at design time. Do you know of any language + C# library that can take a template at runtime and compile it?

Comment: @Ahmet all of those libraries I mentioned perform runtime template processing, T4 is the only one which has the option to run at compile time afaik. Another good one is StringTemplate, although all of these might be slightly overkill for your purposes - a simpler markup language like bbcode, mediawiki or markdown would be a simpler solution, as mentioned in tripleees answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use an existing markup convention? There are plenty of lightweight syntaxes to choose from; depending on your user population, some of them might already be familiar with MediaWiki markup and/or BBcode and/or reST and/or Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using \ to escape {} chars in the text and un-escaped {} to surround a subsection. This is how C# handles " chars in a string. Using double braces introduces ambiguities and makes correctly processing the text difficult, if not impossible. Your choice also depends on your target users. Developers are comfortable using escape chars but they can be confusing to non-dev users. You might want to use tags like `<sub>` and `</sub>` to indicate a subsection. Either way, you can use a regular expression to parse the user's text into a RegEx.Matches collection.